# Haskell: class and function overloading:

Tags: haskell

I am quite new to Haskell. I am trying to overload a custom function 'myadd' for different containers. My understanding is that you have to do it through classes. This is what i tried:

```
class Addition a where
  myadd :: a -> a -> a

instance Addition Int where
  myadd a b = a + b

instance Addition Maybe where
  myadd (Just a) (Just b) = Just (a + b)

main = do
  let a = 3 :: Int
  let b = 4
  let c = myadd a b
  print c

  let d = (Just a)
  let e = (Just b)
  let f = myadd d e
  print f
```

But i get the following errors:

```
test.hs:7:19: error:
    ? Expecting one more argument to ‘Maybe’
      Expected a type, but ‘Maybe’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    ? In the first argument of ‘Addition’, namely ‘Maybe’
      In the instance declaration for ‘Addition Maybe’
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Addition` has kind `* -> *`, so the argument to `Addition` must be of kind `*`. `Maybe` has kind `* -> *`. You need to pass an additional type argument to `Maybe` so that it has kind `*`.

```
instance Addition (Maybe a)
```

The problem with this is that `Maybe a` is not an instance of `Addition` for arbitrary `a`, only for `a` which are already instances of `Addition`. You can specify the requirement that `a` is an instance of `Addition`  like this:

```
instance Addition a => Addition (Maybe a)
```

Also your implementation should use `myadd` instead of `+`:

```
instance Addition a => Addition (Maybe a) where
   myadd (Just a) (Just b) = Just (myadd a b)
```

Comment: Nice way to define an instance with an existing instance.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing so would be through

```
instance (Num a) => Addition (Maybe a) where
    myadd (Just x) (Just y) = Just (x + y)
```

Note the following:

- `Maybe a` is an instance of `Addition`, not `Maybe`.
- The instance is constrained to types `a` where `Num a`.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I tried `instance (Int a) => Addition (Maybe a) where` before. But i guess `Int` won't work since it is not a data constructor or class. I personally think that `Num a` is redundant since operator `+` implies it is of Num class. But i digress.

Comment: @user3689034 If Haskell was made so that `Num a` was redundant because of that, you could no longer tell from the type signature what instances the type variables must have and that would fundamentally change the Haskell type system. You would lose out on really nice things like parametricity: For example, as it is, given a function of type `f :: [a] -> [a]`, you know that it cannot "inspect" or make a modified version of any list item, it must only repeat, rearrange, drop, some combination of those three or be the constant function that always gives back the empty list. That is guaranteed.

Comment: @user3689034 @DavidYoung, or rather, *yes* `Num a` is redundant.  Redundancy is one of the main things types provide.